# Binding not working for Knockout, ReferenceError when ko.applybindings on specific element

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have this ajax to get the data

```
var homeSummaryViewModel;

$(document).ready(function () {
    getHomeSummaryViewModel();

});
function getHomeSummaryViewModel() {

    $.ajax({
        url: "/api/homeservice/get",
        type: "get",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (result) {            
            homeSummaryViewModel = ko.mapping.fromJSON(result);

            ko.applyBindings(homeSummaryViewModel, $("#homeSummary").get(0));

        },
        error: function (result) {
            //handle the error, left for brevity
        }
    });
}
```

Here is my html

```
        <div class="plan-name-bronze">
            <h4>Home</h4>
            <div class="icon">
                <i class="fa fa-trophy fa-5x"></i>
            </div>

        </div>
        <ul class=" text-left" id="homeSummary">
            <li class="plan-feature">Completed Level : <span data-bind="text: Level"></span> </li>                
            <li class="plan-feature">Total Score : <span data-bind="text: Score"></span> </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my JSON

```
{"Level":"Noob","Score":788}
```

**I get this error below in knockout-3.0.0.debug.js, when id do homeSummaryViewModel.peek() i get null. i see the data is sent from server in firebug as show above JSOn Data, ko.mapping does not throw error it just is not working maybe???**

> ReferenceError: Level is not defined    return new Function("$context",
>   "$element", functionBody);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i had to use

```
homeSummaryViewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(result);
```

instead  of

```
homeSummaryViewModel = ko.mapping.fromJSON(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `value` binding is only for form-input elements; you need to be using the `text` binding.

Comment: i tired text as well  and had same results that is why i switched to see if value would work. neither works.

Comment: Show a little more context around the JS code and the HTML.

Comment: added some JS and html

Comment: maybe i need to check what is populated into that model but when i do console.log(homeSummaryViewModel) i only get observable()

Comment: i am getting null when do .peek() , that means its not mapping it , i can see that JSOn in firebug comming back successfully and no error when ko.mapping executes, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you binding with the $.get, I created a simple test case http://jsfiddle.net/PB9KL/, it works fine.

```
var homeSummaryViewModel;
getHomeSummaryViewModel();


function getHomeSummaryViewModel() {

            homeSummaryViewModel = ko.mapping.fromJSON('{"Level":"Noob","Score":788}');

            ko.applyBindings(homeSummaryViewModel,document.getElementById("homeSummary"));

}
```